# Is it Possible to mock SLF4J Logger in NPM Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, npm, jestjs

I have code where SLF4J logger has been utilize to log the error or debug.

logfuntest.js:

```js
function someLoggerFunction() {
  logger.log("some important logs");
}
 
module.exports = someComplexFunction
```

I need to test Logger in Jest using NPM, let me do how we can mock/spy on for Logger.

I tried but not working, I am not sure how to import the dependency in NPM.

Comment: Where does the `logger` come from? What have you tried?

Comment: Can you provide the complete code and what code does not work?

Comment: please refer below code for test file.

Answer (score 0):

Below is my code

so logger is object of Logger class from npmlog package. this is my test file code
logfuntest.test.js

```js
let {someLoggerFunction}= require("../main/logfuntest")   
test('test the logger', () => {
    const logger = require('npmlog');
    const info = jest.spyOn(logger, "info").mockImplementation(() => {});
    someLoggerFunction();
    expect(info).toHaveBeenCalledWith('some important logs');
    info.mockReset();
});
```

in above logfuntest.js code please correct logger.info